# Python timeit trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

I ran into trouble using (understanding) the Python timeit function. When I use timeit.timeit(“code snippet”, number = n) the result grows proportionally with n, whereas I thought it should give me the best time out of n trials of a single execution of the code snippet.

The following code demonstrates what I mean:

```
import math
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_values = [10**i for i in range(8)]
t_values = [[timeit.timeit("pass", number=n) for n in n_values] for _ in range(10)]

for t in t_values:
    plt.plot(n_values, t)
plt.xlabel('number')
plt.ylabel('time (seconds)')
plt.title('timeit.timeit("pass", number=n)')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In addition to the time growing with n, I find that the first series of results (blue line) is an order of magnitude slower than the rest.

Clearly I am not using the timeit function properly.

Comment: _"result grows proportionally with n, whereas I thought it should give me the best time out of n trials"_: the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) are pretty clear that `timeit` _"time[s] `number` executions of the main statement"_

Comment: In my case the main statement is pass ?!

Comment: Thanks, the part near the end of the final response where it says: “…and returns the sum of time it took to execute all number times.” certainly explains why the time grows proportionally with “number”.  I am still puzzled why the first series is an order of magnitude slower.